# Understanding how a try except logic works within two while loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, try-catch

I'm having trouble understanding the mechanism of my code. I want to retrieve the realtime price data of a crypto from an exchange and print it every second, while creating a retry mechanism that catches an exception when it occurs.

```
while True:
    try_cnt = 10
    while try_cnt > 0:
        try:
            price = get_current_price(symbol)           # function imported from elsewhere
            print(price)
            time.sleep(1)
            try_cnt = 0
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            try_cnt -= 1
```

This is how I have it set up but I'm having trouble follow the logic. This is how I see it as of now. After the code has been run:

1. Price is retrieved
2. try_cnt is set to 0 and the second while loop is broken
3. The next second, try_cnt is reset to 10 and price is retrieved
4. try_cnt is set to 0 again and the second while loop is broken
5. repeat of this process

Am I understanding this correctly?

**EDIT**: the reason why I have a while loop outside is that I have other things that are going on at **specific times** besides the part I mentioned here. The part that I mentioned is supposed to be running all the time every second. For example,

```
while True:
    if now.hour == 0 and now.minute == 0 and now.second == 0:
        A = functionA(x,y)
    try_cnt = 10
    while try_cnt > 0:
        try:
            price = get_current_price(symbol)           # function imported from elsewhere
            print(price)
            time.sleep(1)
            try_cnt = 0
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            try_cnt -= 1
```

Comment: You don't need `try_cnt = 0`, since `break` ends the loop and the condition is not checked.

Comment: But yes, you're understanding correctly. If an exception occurs, you don't break out of the loop, and keep retrying until `try_cnt` gets to `0`. You could also use `for _ in range(10):`

Comment: What's the point of the outer `while` loop @jy2da? If the point of this is to try getting the price 10 times, the inner `while` loop should be enough.

Comment: @janq0 Good point. Please see my edit in the main post. Does that now make sense/seem acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are understanding everything just fine, but the code itself is a little silly and redundant. For example, setting `try_cnt` to `0` and then following that with `break` is pointless - both lines do the same thing. And unless there is some significance to the variable `try_cnt` that is not present within the code you posted, its existence seems pretty much useless to me. Here's code that does the exact same thing as the code above, but without the redundancies:

```
while True:
    try:
        price = get_current_price(symbol)
        print(price)
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

In response to your edit, the `while True` loop encompassing everything makes a lot more sense. However, this means that your code isn't doing what you want it to do. The outer `while` loop ensures that even if `try_cnt` reaches `0`, `try_cnt` will just be reset to `10` on the next pass and it will be as if no `Exception`s ever occurred (besides the ten error messages in the console). If you want that inner `while` loop to stop executing when ten `Exception`s occur, you need to place the `try_cnt = 10` statement outside of both `while` loops like so:

```
try_cnt = 10
while True:
    if now.hour == 0 and now.minute == 0 and now.second == 0:
         A = functionA(x,y)
    while try_cnt > 0:
        try:
            price = get_current_price(symbol)           
            print(price)
            time.sleep(1)
            try_cnt = 10
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            try_cnt -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want it to retry a certain number of times until it raises the exception? Wouldn't your code retry an infinite number of time?

Comment: Hopefully, the second part of my answer clarifies that for you.

Comment: I explained why I have a while loop outside. Does that make sense/seem acceptable now?

Comment: What I wanted to see was the code printing the current price every second in an infinite, while catching an exception and retrying the code 10 times before quitting. Hopefully the error is resolved within 10 tries and the code keeps printing the price every second again.

Comment: I think my new edit should help with that. One quick additional note though - that if loop will likely run several times at once before its time window closes - you might want to add a `time.sleep(1)` after the `A = functionA(x,y)` to fix that.

Comment: Happy to be of help!

Comment: Not sure if you'll get to this comment, but I have one quick question. What is the purpose of try_cnt = 10 in the try block? Specifically, I'm not fully understanding why there is try_cnt outside the first while loop and also in the try block.

Comment: The `try_cnt = 10` inside of the `try` block is there so that `try_cnt` is reset to `10` on every iteration. My assumption was that you wanted `try_cnt` to be reset to `10` if an `Exception` was caught, say, 5 times but then not caught on the sixth. If, in that scenario, you would not want `try_cnt` to be reset, then you would delete that line in the `try` block. The point of declaring `try_cnt = 10` outside of the `while` loop is just so that the compiler will know what `try_cnt` is on the first iteration of that `while` loop.

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thanks again!